# HttpSendRequest fails with error 12152, but InternetOpenUrl doesn't

Tags: windows, winapi, wininet

When trying to send a get request, using `HttpSendRequest`, to a website, note that this has been tried on multiple sites (`google`, `stackoverflow`, `youtube`, etc.), a error occurs, error 12152 (`The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response`).

When using Fiddler to get a more normal response, this is the error `[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.`

Oddly enough, `InternetOpenUrl` doesn't fail even tho all of the same parameters are used. Here is my code:

```cpp
HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenW(..., DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

HINTERNET hHttp = InternetConnectW(hInternet, L"stackoverflow.com", 443, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);

static const WCHAR anyAccept[] = { '*','/','*', 0 };

LPCWSTR accept[2] = { anyAccept, NULL };

HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(hHttp, L"GET", L"/", NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);

HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

//InternetOpenUrlW(hInternet, L"https://stackoverflow.com/", NULL, 0, 0, 0);
```

As far as I can tell, looking at the source posted on [ReactOS](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d2a/dll_2win32_2wininet_2internet_8c.html#a914af2169fe9d05020ad041019c75afc), `InternetConnectW`, using the http service, uses `HTTP_Connect`, just like `InternetOpenUrl`, only difference is that in OpenUrl it sets the `dwInternalFlags` parameter to `INET_OPENURL` while in Connect it sets it to 0 but after that, all is the exact same sins OpenUrl also uses `HttpOpenRequestW` & `HttpSendRequestW`, so what's the issue, how come doing `Connect => OpenRequest(GET) => SendRequest` results in error code 12152 but doing OpenUrl, which is the same thing under the hood, completes successfully?

Comment: What does the actual response look like?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't get a response when using SendRequest, unless Fiddler is open, all i get is `false` as the return value and `GetLastError()` is 12152. Also, `HttpQueryInfo` doesn't work after the call to `HttpSendRequest` with the error being that the request isn't in the correct state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to estabilsh a secure section over 443 port, but you are missing the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag in `HttpOpenRequest` call.

[MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpopenrequestw)

Change:

```
HttpOpenRequestW(hHttp, L"GET", L"/", NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);
```

to:

```
HttpOpenRequestW(hHttp, L"GET", L"/", NULL, NULL, accept, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
```

Comment: You are right, man I am dumb, even in the provided ReactOS link it has the line `if (urlComponents.nScheme == INTERNET_SCHEME_HTTPS) dwFlags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;`, and the `dwFlags` are used in both the `Http_Connect` and `HttpOpenRequest`, thanks for the help, can't believe I overlooked it xD